# Is there a Filter that I can use to filter the tags before they are inserted in to the database?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, tags

I want to filter the tags before they are inserted into the database. I'm aware of the [pre_insert_term](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/pre_insert_term) filter. But what I need to do is to see all the tags at once. I need to limit the number of tags entered to the database per post. Is there a filter to do this? Or any other method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A good thing *- as always -* is the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

You could `count` the terms from the `$post` data on `pre_post_update`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did take a look at that. But from what I understood, it is an action and not a filter. A $post_id is passed to it according to the [source](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/pre_post_update?version=3.1&file=wp-includes/post.php). So I don't think that will work. Even if I get the post using the $post_id, it will return what is in the database right? What I want is to filter this before it gets to the database.

Comment: Filters & Actions are just different names. Take a look at /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 324.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `wp_set_post_tags()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags)) to modify the number of tags, and then hooking that into `save_post` or `publish_post` or wherever, as appropriate?

e.g.

```
function mytheme_limit_post_tags( $post_id ) {
    // code to count/limit the number of tags
    // then pass the modified list of tags to wp_set_post_tags
    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tags, false );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'mytheme_limit_post_tags' );
```